# Корректно ли словосочетание "правовые правила"?

Tags: стилистика

*Правовые правила* — корректное словосочетание?

Answer (score 1):

Как масло масляное. Лучше *правовые нормы* или *юридические правила*, то есть сделать так, чтобы в составе словосочетания не повторялся один и тот же корень. Такая избыточность допустима иногда в художественной речи, но, видимо, это не тот случай.